# Fixing Style Layout for MediaWiki SpecialPages

Tags: css, mediawiki

The skin I've installed (foreground) runs fine on all my pages including special pages except the login account page.

I've tried going to my `skins/foreground/assets/stylesheets` folder and do some editing on their CSS scripts, but they just implement minor changes.

I want to see if there's a way I can **rebuild/modify** the CSS or general template of just the login page, with the foreground skin I've already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Many wikis use pages like MediaWiki:Common.css to create a custom 'theme' for their wiki. However, due to security reasons, site-wide CSS on restricted special pages was disabled starting with MediaWiki versions 1.19.20.

By default such style sheets no longer load on login or preference pages creating an inconsistent user interface. In order to fix the **UI** you need to set the variable: `$wgAllowSiteCSSOnRestrictedPages` to `true` in `LocalSettings.php`.

This will enable the skin for the special pages mentioned.